# Multivariate normal random variables with identical mean and covariance have the same distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Consider two multivariate normal random variables $\boldsymbol{Y}\sim N_n(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{V})$ and $\boldsymbol{W}\sim N_n(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{V})$. I'd like to show that $\boldsymbol{Y}=^{d}\boldsymbol{W}$.

The reason I'm asking is because if we know $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\boldsymbol{b}$ and $\boldsymbol{V}=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{A}^\top$ explicitly, $\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{Z}+\boldsymbol{b}$ may not be unique or well-defined. Since matrix square roots are not unique, we may find another decomposition $\boldsymbol{B}\neq\boldsymbol{A}$ but $\boldsymbol{V}=\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{B}^\top$.

I am trying to show $M_{\boldsymbol{Y}-\boldsymbol{W}}(\boldsymbol{t})$
(the MGF ) has zero mean and covariance, but the calculation is messy since no independence assumptions between these two RV's are given. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $Y-W$ does not have to have zero covariance even in the simple case where $V=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and the distributions are obviously identical (for example you could have $Y_1=W_2$ and $Y_2=W_1$) so that approach will not work

Comment: @Henry Are there other approaches to justify this?

Comment: My initial thought was that $Y$ and $W$ have the same joint density as each other (using $V$ not $A$) and so the same distribution, with some adjustment in degenerate cases